# What is the difference between (int*) arr[2] and int* arr[2]?

Tags: c

Does (int*) arr[2] have to with typecasting? If yes, where is it used?

This problem arose when I tried to compile the follwing code :

```
    int* arr[2];
    int arr1[] = { 1,2};
    int arr2[] = { 1,6};
    arr[0] = arr1;
    arr[1] = arr2;
```

by replacing

```
int* arr[2] with (int*)arr[2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `(int*) arr[2];` would be a cast expression, casting `arr[2]` to `int*`. But `arr` has probably not been declared, and the compiler barfs.

Comment: Typecasting on declaration? I thought it was a pointer to an array of ints..

Comment: @LewsTherin That would be `int (*arr)[2];`. And with the parentheses, it's not a declaration. It's just an expression without effect then (apart from the fact that `arr` has not been declared).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ugh yeah!

Comment: I don't get why he'd want to cast an `int` to an `int*`.. what is he trying to do? :S

Comment: It wasn't intended. Just a trick question on pointers.

Comment: Another ugh moment, but OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one makes `arr` as an array of pointers to int. So your `arr` is a variable. That is a declaration line.

The second one: assuming that `arr` is a an array (which was allready declared!), takes the value which is `arr[2]` and casts a `pointer to int` type on it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with replacing `int *arr[2]` with `(int *) arr[2]` in your context is that the latter no longer conforms to the C grammar for declarations. According to the structure of C grammar, in `int *arr[2]` the `*` is attached to `arr`, not to `int`. Forcing it towards `int` by using extra `()` violates the suffix of a declaration.

You are allowed to use `()` in C declarations as long as it doesn't violate the syntactic structure of a declaration imposed by C grammar. For example, you can do

```
int *(arr)[2]; // same as `int *arr[2]`
```

or

```
int *(arr[2]); // same as `int *arr[2]`
```

or

```
int (*arr)[2]; // different from `int *arr[2]`, but still valid
```

but not your `(int *) arr[2]` or `(int) *arr[2]`. The latter are not declarations.